# Infinite distribution of charge vs infinite distribution of matter

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, charge, matter

From my textbook:

> General Relativity is the currently most complete theory of Gravitation,
> and should be used to describe physical systems each time one of the
> following assumptions does not hold:
>
> - Gravitational fields are small, $\Phi << c^2$
> - The scale of the system is much smaller than the curvature radius
> - Velocities are small $v << c$

> A way to satisfy these hypotheses in cosmology is to consider the evolution
> of a small spherical portion of the Universe, where Newton’s theory
> applies: then, the behaviour of this portion will reflect the evolution of
> the Universe (see below). 
> Two important notes:
>
> - We can use the Newtonian Gravitation here only because we can
>   neglect the matter outside the sphere does not affect the field gravitational
>   field inside the sphere: this is a consequence of Gauss’s
>   theorem, which in GR is known as Birchoff’s theorem.

**Important part:**

> In principle, the same applies to an infinite distribution of charges. 
> However there is a fundamental difference between the electrical
> and the gravitational field: the former is measurable, while the second
> is not (because of the equivalence principle). In gravitation,
> only tidal fields can be measured! As a result, an infinite distribution
> of charges does not make sense (for a finite sphere of charges,
> the electrical field gives the center of the sphere, so the limit $R\to \infty$
> is not allowed: where is the center then?). But an infinite distribution
> of matter is allowed in Newton’s theory (the gravitational field
> increases linearly with R, which means that the tidal field is constant;
> also, the tidal fields is isotropic and no direction for a center
> is provided!)

- Why is the tidal field constant? I don't understand this.
- Shouldn't the gravitational field **decrease** linearly with $R$? (there is written increase).
- So the main difference is that the Electric field goes as $\displaystyle\frac{1}{R^2}$ outside a charged sphere while the Gravitational Field goes as $\displaystyle\frac{1}{R}$, right?
- Is really the Birchoff theorem the GR version of the Gauss
  theorem?

Comment: Which textbook is this?

Comment: I have edited the question with the full part of the chapter to avoid misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1):

To answer two of your questions:

We're interested in what happens inside the sphere, not outside it, since the sphere will fill all of space as $ R\rightarrow \infty $. Inside the sphere, both the electric field and the gravitational field are proportional to $R$. "Increase" is correct.

The main difference is *not* that the electric field and the gravitational field behave differently. The main difference is that the gravitational field is not observable. The tidal field is the observable thing.